# RewriteRule acting strange

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want URL like this: `localhost/dir/images/pic1.jpg`

to be rewriten to: `localhost/dir/subdir/index.php?folder=images&picture=pic1.jpg`

So i put really simple .htaccess file in `localhost/dir/`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)$ subdir/index.php?folder=$1&picture=$2 [L]
```

and expect to get `folder='images'` and `picture='pic1.jpg'` in `localhost/dir/subdir/index.php` but instead I have `folder='subdir'` and `picture='index.php'`

Strange thing is that when i modify .htaccess file to call index.php from the same directory (not from 'subdir') it works well:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)$ index.php?folder=$1&picture=$2 [L]
```

I get `folder='images'` and `picture='pic1.jpg'` in `localhost/dir/index.php` script

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is happening because your rewrite rule is looping and matching target string `subdir/index.php` with the pattern `.*/.*`.

Use this condition to stop the loop:

```
RewriteEngine On

# If the request is not for a valid directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# If the request is not for a valid file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)$ subdir/index.php?folder=$1&picture=$2 [L]
```

Comment: I didn't realise that single rule may be called more than once. I read few tutorials and none of them mentioned this or warned about possibility of loop. They should put this in big red letters ;) Thanks a lot!

Comment: Glad it worked for you. Yes most of tutorials focus on semantics but don't explain how the whole flow words.